# Knowing that specific matrix is nondiagonizable $\rightarrow a=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Say we have a matrix

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1 \\ 
 0& a
\end{bmatrix}$

Say that we know that $A$ is not diagonalisable (and therefore it can't have two distinct eigen values). I'm reading a text that says from this information, it follows that $a=1$.

Can somebody explain to me why this is? Thanks!

Comment: $A$ is triangular, hence its diagonal consists of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Given the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1 \\ 
 0& 2
\end{bmatrix}$

What vector would have an eigenvalue of 2? would it be any scalar multiple of $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Try solving for $\mathbf x$ when $A\mathbf{x} = a\mathbf{x}$ and convince yourself that $a$ is always an eigenvalue. Now find when these two eigenvectors for each of $1$ and $a$ are linearly independent. If they are, then they form a basis, so diagonalizability follows. That leaves only $a=1$, for which one can argue non-diagonalizability.